# Check if multiple records exist, with the same id

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by

I am trying to check if multiple records exists with `pageId IN(?,?,?)` in the `chatParticipants` table.

This is an example of the table structure:
[image]

This is the SQL query I have tried:

```
SELECT chatId FROM chatParticipants GROUP BY chatId
HAVING SUM(pageId NOT IN('deb47fba9bc6936ed76e831578baa480','123')) = 0
```

**Expected behavior:**

- If a conversation already exists, with the given (x) participants, that is, with the same `chatId` value, then it must return the `chatId` value.

The above SQL does work, with two inputs. However, the below query still returns the `chatId`, which it should not. (As it has the '144' which is not a participant)

```
SELECT chatId FROM chatParticipants GROUP BY chatId
HAVING SUM(pageId NOT IN('deb47fba9bc6936ed76e831578baa480','144','123')) = 0
```

Any ideas why it does this? I only want to get an output, if all the participants match in the query, and has the same chatId.

**Edit 2:**

[image]

This SQL will return two chat IDs.

```
SELECT chatId FROM chatParticipants WHERE pageId 
IN ('123','deb47fba9bc6936ed76e831578baa480') GROUP BY chatId HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

Output:

```
016030f5ba6d47c31f7f22d92507faf1
43bcd7340f1abf7eda09fcccffdbfe60
```

When in fact, the expected output should only return the chat id for `43bcd7340f1abf7eda09fcccffdbfe60`

Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure why the `SUM()` is being used on a column that contains NON Numeric data

Comment: @RiggsFolly: this `SUM`s the boolean conditions - in MySQL this is OK.

Comment: @GMB Learn something on all the good days :)

Comment: What is your version of MySql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could this solve your problem?

```
SELECT chatId FROM chatParticipants WHERE chatId IN (
  SELECT chatId FROM chatParticipants WHERE pageId
  IN ('123','deb47fba9bc6936ed76e831578baa480') GROUP BY chatId HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
) GROUP BY chatId HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Daniele. The reason, is that I would like to check if a conversation exists exactly between X participants, with the same chatId, to redirect to that conversation, instead of creating a new one. If user A wants to start a chat with B (only) then it shouldn't redirect to the chat where possible user A,B,C is in. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Crystal clear @Anders . Could you please check my edited answer?

Comment: Just tried it, seems to work as intended. Can this be made into a single query (Not two seperate SELECT)? Probably won't mean much performance wise, but just wanted to check. Nonetheless, it does appear to solve the question I asked, so will upvote, and mark as a solution. Thanks again. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `WHERE` clause to filter on the list of pages you are interested in, and then ensure that they were all found with a `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT chatId 
FROM chatParticipants 
WHERE pageId IN ('deb47fba9bc6936ed76e831578baa480','123', '144')
GROUP BY chatId
HAVING COUNT(*) = 3
```

This assumes not duplicate `pageId` per `chatId`. Otherwise, you can use `COUNT(DISTINCT pageID)` instead of `COUNT(*)`.

Comment: . . Hey, this query seems to get multiple chatIds, when, lets say page (A,B) is in a conversation of its own, and (A,B,C) is in another. I have updated the image of the table, any idea on how to work around this? Thanks..

Comment: Also tried using the COUNT(DISTINCT pageId) as you suggested, but still returned the same output.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the list of `pageId`s of the operator `IN` with a comma separated list and use `GROUP_CONCAT()`:

```
SELECT chatId
FROM chatParticipants 
GROUP BY chatId
HAVING GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT pageId ORDER BY pageId) = '123,144,deb47fba9bc6936ed76e831578baa480'
```

You may remove `DISTINCT` of there is no case of duplicates `pageId`s for each `chatId`.
The values in the comma separated list must be sorted alphabetically.

Or with a subquery that uses `UNION ALL` to return the `pageId`s that you search for:

```
SELECT chatId
FROM chatParticipants 
GROUP BY chatId
HAVING GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT pageId ORDER BY pageId) = (
  SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(pageId ORDER BY pageId) FROM (
    SELECT '123' pageId UNION ALL 
    SELECT '144' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'deb47fba9bc6936ed76e831578baa480' 
  ) t
)
```

In this case the order of the `pageId`s is not of any importance because they are sorted later by `GROUP_CONCAT()`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion forpas. I did try something similar to this previously. How would you suggest making the prepared statement, to prevent attacks, using a comma separated string? And will the order of the list have any significance? The page id's are not preselected by me, as they are dynamic to the users choosing, and may be in different order.

Comment: For the 1st query you should use a prepared statement with 1 `?` placeholder like: `SELECT chatId...HAVING GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT pageId ORDER BY pageId) = ?` and then pass the string of the comma separated list. In Java it would be something like: `preparedStatement.setString(1, listOfValues);` but the variable `listOfValues` must contain the pageIds sorted. So you must do the sorting of the list before and then concatenate the values with `,` as separator. For the 2nd query you must use 1 `?` placeholder for each of  the the pageIds which don't need to be sorted.